# How to break foreach loop in xtend?

Tags: xtend

I have below code : Which is iterating the arrayList till end even though I don't want it. I don't know how to break it as xtend does not have break statement. Provided I can't convert the same to a while loop, is there any alternative way in xtend similar to break statement in java?

```
arrayList.forEach [ listElement | if (statusFlag){
     if(monitor.canceled){
          statusFlag = Status.CANCEL_STATUS
          return
     }
     else{
          //do some stuff with listElement
     }      
}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like that

```
arrayList.takeWhile[!monitor.cancelled].forEach[ ... do stuff ...]
if ( monitor.cancelled ) { statusFlag = Status.CANCEL_STATUS }
```

takeWhile is executed lazily, so it should work as expected and break at correct moment (memory visibility allowing, I hope monitor.cancelled is volatile).

Not sure how status flag comes into picture here, you might need to add check for it in one or both closures as well.

Comment: Nice, much more concise than using exceptions!

Answer (score 3):

You are right, `break` and `continue` is not supported by Xtend.

Because it seems that you would like to 'break' based on an external condition (so you can't use e.g. filtering) I think it's not a bad option to throw an exception.

Pseudo code:

```
try {
    arrayList.forEach[
        if (monitor.canceled) {
            throw new InterruptedException()
        }
        else {
            // Continue processing
        }
    ]
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // Handle
}
```

Comment: thanks snorbi. It is working perfectly and cancels the monitor. But only in debug mode in eclipse with a a debug point at monitor.canceld... During runtime/disabling the debug points,never works in eclipse. Strangely never  halts at a debug point if I run the job first then put the debug point too. I am running the monitor inside runInWorkspace() method of eclipse WorkspaceJob.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help without the full related code provided. I think that there is a multi-threading problem in your application. I suggest to take a look at how the "volatile" keyword works in Java, or even better you should use concurrency utilities like AtomicBoolean.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, break and continue is not supported by Xtend.
Move break specific functionality to java and use that in xtend.